# Como tornar o uso do snippet mais intuitivo

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, stack-snippets

> **Nota:** Hoje percebi que o problema realmente está acontecendo nas demais comunidades, eu abri uma questão no [http://meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247424/how-to-make-snippet-use-more-intuitive)

Eu percebo que desenvolvedores que veem tirar duvidas aqui costumam usar os *snippets* pra tudo, `ruby`, `vb`, `java`, `php`, etc, mesmo estando implícito nos campos de texto as palavras `html`, `css` e `javascript`.

Entendo que exista a necessidade de manter os códigos de preferência no *snippets* do que em outros "externos" como *jsfiddle*, pelo motivo de que se o servidor "externo" cair não terá como ver os códigos.

Eu sei que parece desnecessário, mas eu vejo assim, melhor um **Javascript/CSS/HTML com marcação e sem snippet** do que um **Ruby com snippets**.

Eu sugiro uma destas opções:

> São apenas sugestões e claramente devem ser direcionadas ao http://meta.stackexchange.com, aqui só queremos discutir ideias.

1. (Sugerido pelo @Bacco) Mudar as posições do ícones:

   [image: simulação de tela]

   <sub>Nota do Bacco: "simulei o botão `code`, mas na verdade precisa mais que isso, pois nativamente os icones já estão misturando inserção de objetos, formatação de bloco e formatação inline. Provavelmente a sequência seria:

   Bold, Itálico, Link | Bloco de Código, Bloco de Citação | Imagem, Snippet

   efetivamente agrupando por 'inline', 'bloco' e 'objetos'."</sub>

2. *Snippet* só liberado para questões com TAGs `CSS`, `HTML`, `Javascript` (esse "talvez" seja difícil de implementar).

Comment: @Bacco Pela primeira vez eu vi o mal uso do snippet no [SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28078420/1), não sei se é este novo visual do SOen, mas parece que realmente é um problema de "intuitividade" do SO.

Comment: Acho que esse foi um bom exemplo de *edit war* por conta de um snipet mau utilizado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/45531/revisions

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Nossa é verdade, estranhamente você usou a marcação correta na sexta edição e logo em seguida ela usou "snippet" ao invés de seguir o seu exemplo, eu realmente estou em duvida de qual o motivo dos usuários estarem usando isto, agora estou em duvida se realmente é questão de "intuitividade". +1 pelo *edit war*

Comment: Queria saber o porque do -1 aqui.